# React, getting Invalid Hook Call inside my service for creating an axios instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have a simple `service.js` that looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import APIContext from '../context/api/context'

function GetApi() {
  const { API } = useContext(APIContext)
  console.log(API)
  return API
}

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${GetApi()}`,
})

export default api
```

Whenever I try to use the API, it throws me an error saying:

```
Invalid Hook Call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a hook, `useContext` in your case, only in a React component or a custom hook (see [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)).

What you can do is transform your service into a hook:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import APIContext from '../context/api/context'

function useGetApi() {
  const { API } = useContext(APIContext)
  console.log(API)
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: API,
  })
  return api;
}

export default useGetApi;
```

And you use it inside a component or another hook like this:

```
const api = useGetApi();
```

Comment: That makes sense, but can you explain why you didn't have to cap the ```useGetApi```, as in, make it ```UseGetApi```

Comment: It should be `useGetApi` with non capital `u`, that’s how React knows that it’s a hook, like `useState`, `useEffect`…

Answer (score 0):

The thing you show is function and not a functional component, where a hook should live. You must place hooks in the body of functional components, pass states as props and setters as callbacks if you want to use them if child components.

Comment: But then I can't pass it to axios.create

Comment: Once you put ```const { API } = useContext(APIContext)``` in the body of a functional component you can ```const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${API}`}) ```

Answer (score 0):

What does `APIContext` contain? `Function component` means that you must return jsx, technically a react node. So in your case `GetApi` is not a react component but a plain funciton.

Comment: APIContext contains ```const [API, setAPI] = useState('')```